# How to exclude NULLs from ARRAY so query won't fail

Tags: google-bigquery

[ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) aggregate function includes `NULLs` in the arrays it builds. When such arrays are part of query result, query fails with error:

> Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field

i.e. the following query demonstrates it:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x) FROM UNNEST([1,NULL,2,3]) x
```

How can we solve it ?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Glad you asked! BigQuery supports `IGNORE NULLS` and `RESPECT NULLS` modifiers in some of the aggregate functions, including `ARRAY_AGG`, so your query becomes

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x IGNORE NULLS) FROM UNNEST([1,NULL,2,3]) x
```

and it passes producing `[1,2,3]`. More details are in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#controlling-nulls-in-aggregate-functions).

Comment: Why didn't I see this in the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes)? I thought that's where the BigQuery team announces new features.

Comment: It made to the release notes, but they are not yet published.

Comment: why does `ARRAY_AGG` work and show nulls for some queries but for others it says `Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field x`?

Comment: ARRAYs can have NULLs when they are passed inside the query, but the ARRAYs in the final result of the query, which are written to a table have limitation of not allowing NULL elements.

Answer (score 6):

Another interesting use-case would be if you do not want to lose that NULL elements but rather want to substitute it with some default value. For example -999

Below will do this

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(IFNULL(x,-999)) FROM UNNEST([1,NULL,2,3]) x
```

And in case if you want distinct elements only -

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT IFNULL(x,-999)) FROM UNNEST([1,NULL,2,3,1,NULL]) x
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, it perfectly works with subqueries. Thanks Mikhail

Answer (score 4):

Complementing @Mikhail Berlyant's answer, sometimes you want to keep the NULL values somehow but can't use a placeholder. For example, if you want a boolean array with NULLs, where you can't substitute NULL for `true`/`false`.

A nice workaround is wrapping the values inside a STRUCT, then constructing the array:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(x)) AS struct_array FROM UNNEST([1,NULL,2,3]) x
```