# Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field result

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I am trying to run the following query on Google Big Query.

It shows as valid in the console, when running it, I get this error message:

> "Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field result"

How do resolve this?

## standardSQL

```
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?)\:')
    FROM UNNEST(split(V2Themes,',')) AS x
  ) AS result
FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2019-02-02') AND TIMESTAMP('2019-02-02')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584478/how-to-exclude-nulls-from-array-so-query-wont-fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `NULL` value:

```
ARRAY(
    SELECT regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?)\:')
    FROM UNNEST(split(V2Themes,',')) AS x
    WHERE regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?)\:') IS NOT NULL AND 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ARRAY(
      SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'^(.*?)\:')
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Themes,',')) AS x
      WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(x, r'^(.*?)\:') -- << removes nulls from array
    ) AS result
  FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
  WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2019-02-02') AND TIMESTAMP('2019-02-02')
)
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(result) > 0  -- << filters out output with empty array
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want more than just first character before `\:`? here is some tests

```
select
    x,
    regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*?)\\:') as only_first_occurrence_nongreedy,
    regexp_extract(x, r'^(.*)\\:') as only_first_occurrence_greedy,
    regexp_extract_all(x, r'(.*?)\\:') as all_occurrences_nongreedy,
    regexp_extract_all(x, r'(.*?)\\:') as all_occurrences_greedy  -- same as regexp_extract, but returns array
from
    unnest(
        array[
            struct(r'abc\:' as x),
            struct(r'123\:abc\:'),
            struct(r'\:'),
            struct(r'\\')
        ]
    )
```